# how i can measure width of text entity in Eyeshot Vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, eyeshot

I want to measure text width in Vb.net. Just like i have a text entity, i can get or set the text height but unable to get the text width.Just like the text in the code, i want its width , i have set its height to be 0.25 in the constructor.

```
Dim a As Text
a.TextString = "Ahmad"
a.Height = 0.25
a.Plane = Plane.ZX
a.InsertionPoint = New Point3D(xMinGlobal - 2.5, 0, 1.5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the *BoxSize* property of the entity.
If it's Nothing, try calling the *Regen()* method or adding the text entity to the scene.

Comment: Can you please write a code for it.. I have added the entity to block but dont know how to do it using Regen()..

Comment: text.Regen(new RegenParams(0, model1))